# How to continue after error in catch block?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, transactions

I've a requirement where I'm looping through 10 records, and inserting these records into 3 different tables within a transaction. I'm taking a record at a time from while loop with transaction.

My requirement is, If first 8 records are successfully inserted, and if statement fails at 9th record it should log the error and continue to insert 10th record.

Stored procedure should not stop if any row has any error.

I tried putting transaction in child TRY-CATCH block but still failed.

```
BEGIN TRY

DECLARE  @TotalRecord          AS INT = 10
        ,@LoopStartCount       AS INT = 1
        ,@AskPkQuotationId     AS INT;     

--Some select stuff here       
WHILE(@LoopStartCount <= @TotalRecord)
BEGIN 

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN

    --Do some insert update for each record.

    COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

    --Log Error and Continue with next record

    END CATCH
     SET @LoopStartCount = @LoopStartCount + 1;
    END



END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 --Log parent error
END CATCH
```

Comment: so the loop should not stop on errors than why do you need a transaction ?

Comment: @GuidoG What if the selected record raised any error, it should rollback that insert and continue to next record.

Comment: but if the selected record raised an error on insert than it will not be inserted so no need to rollback ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: You have a extra END  before the END TRY. I took that out, dropped in a SELECT 1/0 after BEGIN TRAN to force an error, and your code works fine

Answer (score 4):

Implement try...catch only to your While loop and not to your entire code. I have given you a sample demo here.

```
DECLARE @I INT = 0
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    ID INT identity(1, 1)
    ,c2 INT
    )

INSERT INTO @table (c2)
VALUES (1)
    ,(2)
    ,(0)
    ,(3)
    ,(4)

SELECT *
FROM @Table

WHILE @I < 5
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET @I = @I + 1

        SELECT @I / (
                SELECT c2
                FROM @table
                WHERE ID = @I
                ) AS Quotient
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
            ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
            ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
            ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
            ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
            ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
    END CATCH
END
```

This code returns error at third row but still continue processing till the end.

Comment: In the example above the code outside the TRY is just set up for the test. The basic structure is correct. You put your functional code inside a TRY and you have a CATCH to handle it. You can determine the value of the count inside the CATCH to set the ROLLBACK as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below. In the catch section you can handle the scenario.

```
BEGIN TRY

DECLARE  @TotalRecord          AS INT = 10
        ,@LoopStartCount       AS INT = 1
        ,@AskPkQuotationId     AS INT;     

--Some select stuff here       
WHILE(@LoopStartCount <= @TotalRecord)
BEGIN 

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN 

    --Do some insert update for each record.

    COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
     
    --Log Error and Continue with next record
    IF @@TRANCOUNT >1
    
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.ERROR_DETAILS --INSERTING ErrorInfo INTO LOG TABLE
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
    
    ROLLBACK TRAN 

    END
    GOTO LOOPCOUNTER1
    END CATCH
    LOOPCOUNTER1:
     SET @LoopStartCount = @LoopStartCount + 1;
    END
END

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 --Log parent error
END CATCH
```

Comment: I should rollback transaction in catch block, and this approach didn't work.

Comment: you can add rollback at the catch block itself. try the updated script